# How to Call Java Servelet and get response from it in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servlets

I got a Java Servelet like 
http://152.252.271.12:9999/media/servlet/RequestProcessor.do

for this I need to pass parameters in Querystring like this
http://152.252.271.12:9999/media/servlet/RequestProcessor.do?input=abc

I need to read response back.

---

I tried like this.

```
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(postData);
            }

            // Read Response.

            HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                logtxn.LogTxn(result, "SPDCL RESPONSE");
            }

            webresponse.Close();
```

Any help appreciated..

Comment: If you just need the response use WebClient which has [DownladString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) method. You give it the URL and get back the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WebRequest & WebResponse classes. Check http://gsraj.tripod.com/dotnet/webgetpost.html for more information.

Comment: I used the same. But, it caused the following exception "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past, I had to host a service in IIS that accepted a string containing a request and returned another string with a response to that request. All of the above needed to be done using HTTP POST.

The solution I found was to host a WCF service on IIS and configure it to use HTTP GET/POST protocols.

Also I remember that I needed to use a Stream class to input and output data (a simple string would not work in this case), in other words, I had a HTTP POST method in WCF that was something like:

```
Stream GetData(Stream data);
```

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/HTTP_POST_RestServiceAPI.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebClient` class, as a client for the servlet. For example

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

// Download the Web resource and save it into a data buffer.
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData (@"http://152.252.271.12:9999/media/servlet/RequestProcessor.do?input=abc");

// Display the downloaded data.
string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
```

Now parse the result string `download` and obtain the response.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code:

```
 public class MyWebRequest
    {
        private WebRequest request;
        private Stream dataStream;
        private string status;
        public String Status
        {
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
            set
            {
                status = value;
            }
        }
        public MyWebRequest(string url)
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.
            request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        }
        public MyWebRequest(string url, string method): this(url)
        {
            if (method.Equals("GET") || method.Equals("POST"))
            {
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = method;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");
            }
        }
        public MyWebRequest(string url, string method, string data): this(url, method)
        {
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = data;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        public string GetResponse()
        {
            // Get the original response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            this.Status = ((HttpWebResponse) response)
                .StatusDescription;
            // Get the stream containing all content returned by the requested server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content fully up to the end.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return responseFromServer;
        }
    }




 //create the constructor with post type and few data
    MyWebRequest myRequest = new MyWebRequest("http://www.yourdomain.com", "POST", "a=value1&b=value2");
    //show the response string on the console screen.
    Console.WriteLine(myRequest.GetResponse());
```